# Validate a form using jquery.validate before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to validate my form using jquery.validate plugin. It works fine, but when I am trying to submit using form id, it submits invalid form.

Now I validate using:

```
$("#login_form").validate();
```

The form id is:

```
<form role="form" method = "POST" id="login_form"> ... </form>
```

Now, if validation is not complete, I get an alert using this function:

```
("#login_form").submit(
    function()
    { 
        alert("Please submit");
    }
    );
```

I think, I should not get alert unless I validate my form completely. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [.valid](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) method of jQuery validate

You need to check the form validity inside submit handler and prevent the form submission if **valid** returns false.

Refer this for [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: I have got another issue. Can you help me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225436/valid-from-jquery-returns-true