# .valid from jquery returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to submit my form when `.valid` returns `true`. It works fine with `login_form`, but it is returning `true` for `signup_form`. The `.validate` methods work fine, but when the form is not validated, `.valid` returns `true` for `signup_form`.

```
var login_form = $( "#login_form" );
var signup_form = $( "#signup_form" );
login_form.validate();
signup_form.validate({
    rules:
    {
        signup_repeat_password:
        {
            equalTo:"#signup_password"
        }
    },
    messages:
    {
        signup_repeat_password:
        {
            equalTo:"Please repeat the password"
        }
    }
});

if ( login_form.valid())
{
    login_form.submit(
    function()
    {
        alert("Please submit login_form");
    }
    );
}

if ( signup_form.valid())
{
    signup_form.submit(
    function()
    {
        alert("Please submit signup_form");
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: You need to check the conditions inside submit handler..

Comment: But, it is working great with login_form?

Comment: Try to debug with different scenarios..Do put form validity conditions inside submit callback and check..You have both the forms in the same page, if login form is valid but currently user is trying to submit the signup form then also login form will get submitted..

Comment: signup.valid() is true.

Comment: You need to debug Sir. There are documentation available for all the plugins you are using..